# Pass pointer to c++ function in python

Tags: python, django, pointers, structure, ctypes

i try to call a function of a Windows dll, called DISM.

```
HRESULT WINAPI DismGetLastErrorMessage(
   _Out_ DismString** ErrorMessage 
);
```

Here an example:

```
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
DismString* ErrorMessage;

hr = DismGetLastErrorMessage(&ErrorMessage);
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh824754.aspx

The structure looks like

```
typedef struct _DismString
{
    PCWSTR Value;
}
DismString;
```

while Value is "A null-terminated Unicode string."

Here is my code:
models.py

```
from django.db import models
from ctypes import *

class DismString(Structure):
_fields_ = [("Value", c_wchar_p)]

class DismManager(models.Model):

class Meta:
    abstract = True

def __init__(self, dll):

    self.hDism = OleDLL(dll)



def GetLastErrorMessage(self):
    self.hDism.DismDelete.restype = HRESULT
    self.hDism.DismDelete.argtypes = [POINTER(DismString)]
    s = DismString()
    try:
        test = self.hDism.DismGetLastErrorMessage(byref(s))
        print(test)
        #print(s)
        return s
    except WindowsError as e:
        return print("Error message", e.strerror, "\nError code", e)
```

views.py

```
from ctypes import OleDLL
from django.http import HttpResponse

from api.models import DismManager

def index(request):

    # Load library
    obj = DismManager("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Kits\\8.0\Assessment and Deployment Kit\\Deployment Tools\\amd64\\DISM\\dismapi.dll")

    obj.Init(2, u"C:\\newDism")

    session = obj.OpenSession(u"C:\\mounter") # throws an error
    last_error = obj.GetLastErrorMessage() # want to catch the error with it
    print(last_error.Value) # throws *** UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\ua0b0' in position 1: character maps to <undefined>

    return HttpResponse("Hello, world.")
```

It looks like i am not able to get a proper returning string. I either get an error or an unreadable string.
When i write last.error.encode(), it returns b'\xea\x82\xb0P'.

I hope someone can help.

Comment: You are defining `restype` and `argtypes` for `DismDelete` but calling `DismGetLastErrorMessage`. Could you fix that inconsistency first?

Comment: Define a base class named `DismStructure` that has no fields. Use this as the base class for DISM structures such as `DismString`. Set `DismDelete.argtypes = [POINTER(DismStructure)]`. Set `DismGetLastErrorMessage.argtypes = [POINTER(POINTER(DismString))]`. Instantiate `ps = POINTER(DismString)()`. Call `DismGetLastErrorMessage(byref(ps))`. Get the string value as `s = ps[0].Value`, and then deallocate the structure by calling `DismDelete(ps)`.

Comment: @eryksun You are the best!!!!!!! It works fine. Thank you!